# RabbitMQ as Message Broker used by Spring Websocket dies under load

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-websocket

I develop an application where we need to handle 160k concurrent users which are connected to the backend via a `websocket` connection.

We decided to use the `spring websocket` implementation and `RabbitMQ` as the message broker.

In our application every user needs to subscribe to its user queue `/exchange/amq.direct/update` as well as to another queue where also other users can potential subscribe to `/topic/someUniqueName`.

In our first performance test we did the naive approach where every user subscribes to two new queues.

When running the test `RabbitMQ` dies silently when around 800 users are connected at the same time, so around 1600 queues are active ([See the graph of all RabbitMQ objects here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIezG.png)).

I read though that [you should be careful opening many connections to RabbitMQ](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-19-part4-rabbitmq-13-common-errors.html).

Now I wonder if the [approach that is anticipated by Spring Websocket with opening one queue per user](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) is a conceptional problem for systems with high load or if there is another error in my system.

Comment: out of sheer curiosity: did you try your set-up with Kafka instead of RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting factors for RabbitMQ are usually:

- memory (can be checked in dashboard) that needs to grow with number of messages and number of queues (if you don't use lazy queues that go directly to disk).
- maximum number of file descriptors (at least 1 per connection) that often defaults to too low values on many distributions (ref: https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-April/019615.html)
- CPU for routing the messages

Answer (score 0):

I did find the issue. I actually misconfigured the RabbitMQ service and just gave it a 1024 file descriptor limit. Increasing it solved the issue.